# recored video using UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, ios, video, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm developing an iPhone app that records video. I create a `UIImagePickerController`, limit it to video recording then programatically ask the camera to startVideoCapture. Unfortunatly when I run the app I get the following in the console;

```
"UIImagePickerController: ignoring request to start video capture; camera is not yet ready."
```

how can i handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable reason seems to be the absence of the required key in your info.plist file. You will need to configure `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`. Also, you must implement the delegate object. For details, have a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/TakingPicturesAndMovies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010406.

HTH,

Akshay

Comment: thx a lot for the reference you provide i don't know how to thank you
thx thx thx

Answer (score 3):

There is no delegate callback that tells you when the camera is ready. I tried this but no luck, still your error:

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:[picker cameraDevice]]) {
                [picker takePicture];
}
else {
     NSLog(@"Camera not ready");
}
```

I called take picture after delay of 1.0, 1.5, 2.0 seconds. My observations:

At 1.0 secs: takes the picture but the full shutter closing is not seen on the screen
At 1.5 secs: shutter closing is seen but very little
At 2.0 secs: loads the camera, shows whats on the screen and then takes the picture.

So you might wanna use something between 1.75 to 2.25. Code i used:

```
[picker performSelector:@selector(takePicture) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
```

Comment: @OXXY you're welcome. Although the answer you selected ddnt address ur issue (i checked it) you still selected that as an answer. Thats kind of discouraging

Comment: why you say that?? the answer provide me with a sample code from apple 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/AVCam.zip
you can find it here .it provides me with a program recored video and capture still images and now i am studding the code it will be a kind of you if you help me in studding it :)

Comment: UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities basically lets you check if your device has camera at all which was not your original issue. Your device had camera, it just wasnt ready yet

Comment: can i talk on chat with you ??pls give me an appointment if its possible

Comment: talk about my problem if you don't mined and i wanna apologize from you :)