# Video capturing Issue in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, camera

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [recored video using UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817920/recored-video-using-uiimagepickercontroller)

I am new in **iOS development**. Now i am working on video recording app. But my app sometimes record video. And some times it closes camera Give me warning as

```
UIImagePickerController: ignoring request to stop video capture; camera is not currently capturing video.
```

Comment: Refer [**this Link**](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios) , I think may be helped you.
Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

I am capturing Video and store in document directory like this way:-

```
-(IBAction)cameraLibraryButtonClick:(id)sender{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {              
        UIImagePickerController *videoRecorder = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];  
        videoRecorder.delegate = self;
        NSArray *sourceTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:videoRecorder.sourceType];
        NSLog(@"Available types for source as camera = %@", sourceTypes);
        if (![sourceTypes containsObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie] ) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                                            message:@"Device Not Supported for video Recording."                                                                       delegate:self 
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes" 
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"No",nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            return;
        }
        videoRecorder.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        videoRecorder.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie];           
        videoRecorder.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeLow;
        videoRecorder.videoMaximumDuration = 120;

        self.imagePicker = videoRecorder;                 
        [videoRecorder release];
        [self presentModalViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES];
        newMedia = YES;
    }
    else {
        [self displaysorceError];
    }


}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

        NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
        //self.fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);

        NSString *ZipLibrary = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


    NSString *FileFullPath = [ZipLibrary stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"%@.mp4"];

    NSLog(@"Ziplinrnr oadfjaidfjidfjidjfid %@",FileFullPath);
        [videoData writeToFile:FileFullPath atomically:YES];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}


-(void)displaysorceError{
    UIAlertView *alt = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                        initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                        message:@"Camera Image Sorce Not Available" 
                        delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alt show];
    [alt release];
}
```