# Image is already being captured or camera not yet ready

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I am calling this `takePicture` function 5 times because i neeed to take 5 picture on on click(Burst Mode)

```
for(count=0;count<5;count++)
{
     [picker takePicture];
     [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.5];
     [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate: [NSDate date]];
}
```

I am getting this error `UIImagePickerController: ignoring request to take picture; image is already being captured or camera not yet ready`.

Comment: If you're on iOS5+ see my answer here (describes a way to make sure that the camera is ready to take a picture) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678067/how-to-know-if-iphone-camera-is-ready-to-take-picture/10768237#10768237

Comment: Your ans is related to AVFoundation and i have used  UIImagePickerController

Comment: Please read it more carefully. `AVFoundation` is just the underlying framework that handles all this stuff. You will still be using `UIImagePickerController` and just use the `AVFoundation` to catch the notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but i think camera not yet ready ... Because you are trying to capture images continuously.... I think you will have to delay for few seconds before call take picture method again..... Dont do it in for loop i would like to suggest you please use `NSTimer` instead of looping.

something like this -

Declare

```
-(void)startTimer;
```

and

```
int count;
```

in your .h class then  see below code -

```
-(void)yourTakePictureButtonClick:(id)sender
{
    [self startTimer];
}

-(void)startTimer
{
    count = 0;
    yourTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(myFunctionForClickImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)myFunctionForClickImage
{
    [picker takePicture];
    count ++;
    if (count < 5)
    {
       [yourTimer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi H2SO4 (Nice Name han)

The most probable reason seems to be the absence of the required key in your info.plist file. You will need to configure `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`. Also, you must implement the delegate object. For details, have a look at

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/TakingPicturesAndMovies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010406.

HTH,

Another thing you should release your resources in every call inside loop.

You can delay with following.

```
[picker performSelector:@selector(takePicture) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
```

For more you can visit...

http://highoncoding.com/Articles/856_Building_Instagram_for_the_iPhone_Part_2.aspx

Comment: i have also tried that if i increase delay i could not take 5 picture i can take  take 2 or 3 picture and then i will get such error