# UIImagePickerController delegate is not calling

Tags: objective-c, ipad

Iam using the following code for taking the picture automatically from IPAD front camera:

```
UIImagePickerController *imgPkr = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imgPkr.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imgPkr.delegate = self;

        imgPkr.cameraDevice=UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
        [self presentModalViewController:imgPkr animated:YES];
        imgPkr.showsCameraControls = NO;
        [imgPkr takePicture];
```

But this code Dont take any picture and dont call the delegate:

```
    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
```

Any idea what is wrong with the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first guess is that `[imgPkr takePicture];` is being called before the picker is done being presented. Try it like this:

```
UIImagePickerController *imgPkr = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imgPkr.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imgPkr.delegate = self;

        imgPkr.cameraDevice=UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
        [self presentModalViewController:imgPkr animated:YES];
        imgPkr.showsCameraControls = NO;
        [self performSelector:@selector(takePicture) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];
```

OR

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(takePicture)
                                             name:AVCaptureSessionDidStartRunningNotification 

object:nil];
```

&

```
- (void)takePicture
{
    [imgPkr takePicture];
}
```

Comment: @ShehzadBilal Glad to help. See link in Alladinian's answer for a better way to do this. My way just assumes that the camera session will be started within 1 second whereas his answer listens for a notification from the camera that is send when it is ready to take a picture.

Answer (score 2):

I bet that you get a message in your logs saying that

> UIImagePickerController: ignoring request to take picture; camera is
>   not yet ready.

This is a common problem because the underlying capture session needs some time to start, so you just have to be sure that the camera is ready to take a picture and *then* call `takePicture` method. Now, a way to get notified is explained in detail in my answer here:  [How to know if iPhone camera is ready to take picture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678067/how-to-know-if-iphone-camera-is-ready-to-take-picture/10768237#10768237)
Note though that this method will work on iOS5+ (there is a bug in older versions that prevents the system notifications for this event, contrary to what is described in the documentation). I hope that this helps.

Comment: I beat you by a few seconds, but your answer is definitely better +1

Comment: @MDT Thanx man :) Just as a note to the 'delay` solution: Be careful because in some devices the session needs much more time to start. Apart from that, I guess that it's something that would work on older iOS versions

Comment: Thanks for the advice, yeah I wasn't thinking about it but that's a great point.

Answer (score 0):

another way to wait for camera ready until take picture is completion block ->

```
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES
                 completion:^ {
                     [imagePicker takePicture];
                 }];
```

thank you 'GrandSteph' at 
[iOS taking photo programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694859/ios-taking-photo-programmatically)