# UIImagePicker delegate is not called

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using UIImage Picker but the delegate is not called.

```
- (IBAction)captureVideo:(id)sender {
    self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imgPicker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
    self.imgPicker.delegate = self;
    /* if we want from the library*/
    self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    self.imgPicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];

    [self performSelector:@selector(takePicture) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];
// I added that after an answer I san on SO


}

-(void) takePicture
{
    [self presentModalViewController:self.imgPicker animated:YES];

}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSLog(@"Video chosen");
}
```

I added the delay as I saw in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541277/uiimagepickercontroller-delegate-is-not-calling).

I am running on a device.

Comment: have you tried with kUTTypeImage instead of kUTTypeMovie

Comment: @DineshReddyChennuru it calls the delegate with that, but I want to be able to select videos as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all that method is **deprecated in iOS 3.0**, use instead:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

Be sure also to make your interface **conforms to protocol** `<UIImagePickerDelegate>`.