# Preparing iOS Camera Faster

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there a way to prep the camera any faster when presenting UIImagePickerController?

This question addresses that there is indeed a delay, as well as a way to receive a callback when the camera is ready [How to know if iPhone camera is ready to take picture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678067/how-to-know-if-iphone-camera-is-ready-to-take-picture)

I know this must be possible (snapchat, instagram, etc) all have quite seamless UI's in terms of picture-taking.

I currently just present my imagepicker like so:

```
    _imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    _imagePicker.delegate = self;
    _imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    _imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    _imagePicker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff;
    [self presentViewController:_imagePicker animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

Comment: It seems you answer your own question no ? using the notification center as suggested in your post's [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678067/how-to-know-if-iphone-camera-is-ready-to-take-picture)

Comment: You could set up the image picker before the user tries to take a picture. This wouldn't truly be "faster", but it would appear so to the user.

Comment: @MathieuMeylan no. a delegate callback is not the same as increased speed whatsoever.

Comment: @68cherries well how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think is possible, unless you start to build your own photo picker using AVFoundation and capture movies and photo from there. Build a good photo picker from scratch with the same functionalities is quite expensive task. There are some examples around, the apple [AVCam](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html) is probably the most complete. You can use it as a benchmark and see how is faster than the uiimagepickercontroller

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup the camera before the user tries to take a photo. As I mentioned before, this is not truly faster, but will appear so to the user.

This code will set up the camera asynchronously:

Add `__block` before the `UIImagePickerController` in `_imagePicker`'s declaration.

```
NSOperationQueue *cameraSetupQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
cameraSetupQueue.name = @"camera setup";

[cameraSetupQueue addOperationWithBlock:^(void){

    _imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    _imagePicker.delegate = self;
    _imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    _imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    _imagePicker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff;
}];
```

Put this code somewhere so that it will be executed before the camera needs to be used.

Comment: That's interesting and good but you should always keep in mind the memory that would be used by the picker.