# Front Camera switch goes black

Tags: objective-c, camera, ios8

I am making a app that, in its course, can take a picture with the rear camera and immediately take a picture with the front camera 3 seconds after. I do this by dismissing the previous UIImagePickerController and presenting a UIImagePickerController, where in the completion block of the presentViewController:animated:completion: method I start an NSTimer that calls takePicture after 3 seconds.

This worked like a charm in iOS 7. In iOS 8 however I fail to see the front camera view and I receive this in the console:

`UIImagePickerController: ignoring request to take picture; camera is changing modes.`

What is going on here? Was there an API change? Or is this a x.0 bug?

If any code is needed to help me out I will gladly provide it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know if iPhone camera is ready to take picture?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678067/how-to-know-if-iphone-camera-is-ready-to-take-picture)

Comment: Ooooooh sweet! I was looking for a question like this. I guess I just didn't Google-fu correctly. Will update this question if it helps.

Comment: See, the thing is that the front camera doesn't get ready: it just... hangs. The ViewController pulls up, but the actual image view never does. It just stays black. The method I chose to have called from the "possible duplicate" isn't called either.